# blackberry react to menuitem

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I started writing a bb app with a menu.

My problem is I don't know how to react if the selected item is clicked. The menu contains some fields in a VerticalFieldManager that is added in a class that extends MainScreen.
I'm sorry for asking such basic stuff, but i googled 1.5 hours now and didnt find a solution or example, Its my very first blackberry app.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

This snippet of code defines a new menu item, with a constructor where you specify the label of the menu item and its position on the menu, and a run method which is called when the user clicks on your menu item.

The run method is called on the UI (event) thread, so you are free to update your user interface components from here, or do whatever else you need to do.

I also included a snippet of a screen class that adds the menu item to its menu.

```
final class MyMenuItem extends MenuItem
{
    MyMenuItem()
    {
        super("Menu item text", 100000, 0);
    }

    public void run()
    {
        // The user has clicked on the menu item, and
        // this method was called. Do what you need to do.
    }
}


final class MyScreen extends MainScreen
{
    // ...

    protected void makeMenu ( Menu menu, int instance )
    {
        // let the system build a default menu first
        super.makeMenu(menu, instance);

        // add your menu item to the screen         
        menu.add ( new MyMenuItem() ); 
    }

    // ... 
}
```